# How to set the value of CPATH in the below script. The script does not recognise the classpath in the 2nd line of the below script.

Tags: shell, classpath, ksh

I have to execute the below script

```
export CPATH="cpath=.:/mdcode/mtrxmdsb2/WaferChecks/bin/WaferChecksFile.jar"
/sail/lpp/IBM/Java/1.6.0/jre/bin/java \
    -classpath "$CPATH" com/ibm/md/waferchecks/ReadPasswordMain $1 $2 $3
```

The script accepts 3 arguments. But when im running the script from the cmd prompt, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.md.wafercheck
s.ReadPasswordMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.md.waferchecks.ReadPassword
Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:421)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:652)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
Could not find the main class: com/ibm/md/waferchecks/ReadPasswordMain.  Program
 will exit.
```

I understand that this is a problem with classpath variable not being properly set. I gues im wrong with the syntax somewhere. Can anyone please help with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
export CPATH=".:/mdcode/mtrxmdsb2/WaferChecks/bin/WaferChecksFile.jar"
```

Also you don't have to put shell variable in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `export CPATH=` from the assignment line.  This forced java to look for a file or directory with the name `cpath=.` instead of `.`.

```
#! /bin/bash
jarfile=/mdcode/mtrxmdsb2/WaferChecks/bin/WaferChecksFile.jar
cpath=.:${jarfile?}
```

You don't need the `export`, as you're passing $cpath as an argument to the `java` `-classpath` option.

---

*En passant, you can perform some checks prior to invoking java to eliminate
some trivial errors with the following line:*

```
(< ${jarfile?}) || exit # abort on missing or unreadable file[*]
```

- `${path:?}` *aborts if the path variable is empty or undefined*
- `( < file ) || exit`   *is a minimal test on the ability to open a file for reading.*

*(This is common idiom for bash, ksh93 and zsh.)*

---

The final script then becomes:

```
#! /bin/bash
jarfile=/mdcode/mtrxmdsb2/WaferChecks/bin/WaferChecksFile.jar
cpath=.:${jarfile?}
(< ${jarfile?}) || exit

/sail/lpp/IBM/Java/1.6.0/jre/bin/java \
    -classpath "${cpath?}"  \
    com/ibm/md/waferchecks/ReadPasswordMain $1 $2 $3
```